# Combine parameter value to a variable name in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to pass 'en' as a parameter to test function. but I don't know how to pass the parameter value to a variable to reuse it for other lang. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

```js
function test() {

  var en_ed = CKEDITOR.instances["story_html"].getData();
  var en_ed_text = en_ed;
  en_ed_text = en_ed_text.replace(/\s/g, "");
  en_ed_text = removeHTMLTags(en_ed_text);
  en_ed_text = Encoder.htmlDecode(en_ed_text);

  if (en_ed_footer == en_ed_text) {
    en_ed_text = "";
  }

}
```

EDIT
I want to call a function like this - function test(en); en, de ... want to pass as a parameter to this test function.

actually, I wrote this function for the English language now.  I want to reuse this for other langs. for that, I want to pass other languages to this function. once I passed 'de'  lang it should be assigned to like -

```js
var de_ed = CKEDITOR.instances["story_html"].getData();
var de_ed_text = de_ed;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pass the parameter value to a variable to reuse it for other lang"?

Comment: function test (en); like this i can reuse it for other languages. @Keara

Comment: what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: You mean `function test(lang) { ... someObject[lang+"_ed"]`? You are better off doing `var ed[lang] = ...`

Comment: Are you just talking about how to define your function so your function can use the given argument? Cause you seem to be calling other functions easily enough. @mplungjan Currently his language is in function scope, why do you believe he wants it on the global scope?

Comment: @Icepickle true - but not enough information to see what he wants. My second example would work locally or globally

Comment: actually i wrote this function for english language now.  i want to reuse this for other langs. for that i want to pass other languages to this function. once i passed 'de'  lang it should be assigned to like - var de_ed = CKEDITOR.instances["story_html"].getData();
                var de_ed_text = de_ed;

Comment: Please update your question with expected output

Comment: Since you just remove whitespace, what is the need to be language specific?

Comment: @mplungjan: this is only for english. similarly i have multiple lang editors. so need to do the same functions for all langs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a global var to hold your editors by language, try the following.
I recommend to NOT use the windows scope (`window[lang+"_ed"]`) to hold the vars, but to have your own global var

```js
var editors = {};
editors["en"].footer = ".....";
editors["de"].footer = ".....";

function test(lang) {
  var ed = CKEDITOR.instances["story_html"].getData()
  var text = ed.replace(/\s/g, "");
  text = removeHTMLTags(text);
  text = Encoder.htmlDecode(text);

  editors[lang].text = editors[lang].footer == text ? "": text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any declared variable with `var` keyword you can access with `window["var_name"]`

e.g. `var test ="hello";` is same as `window["test"]`
you can pass params to the `window[]` to get desired dynamic variable naming.

You can do something like this:

*PSEUDO CODE*

```
function test(lang) {

  window[lang+"_ed"] = CKEDITOR.instances["story_html"].getData();
  window[lang+"_ed_text"] = window[lang+"_ed"];
  window[lang+"_ed_text"] = window[lang+"_ed_text"].replace(/\s/g, "");
  window[lang+"_ed_text"] = removeHTMLTags(window[lang+"_ed_text"]);
  window[lang+"_ed_text"] = Encoder.htmlDecode(window[lang+"_ed_text"]);

  if (window[lang+"_ed_footer"] == window[lang+"_ed_text"]) {
    window[lang+"_ed_text"] = "";
  }

}
```

*TEST CALL*

```
<input type="button" onclick='test("en")' value="ën" />
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick='test("de")' value="de" />
```

Comment: I recommend he uses his own var instead of polluting the windows  scope. This answer is in essence identical to mine